# Would rather and than

Tags: past-tense, infinitives, past-participles, would-rather

The sentence

> I would rather walk than take the bus

refers to the present-future.
Which of the following sentences, that refer to the past, is the correct one?

I would rather have walked than take the bus.

I would rather have walked than have taken the bus.

I would rather have walked than taken the bus.

Comment: ***Last year,** I would rather walk than take the bus, but since firing my personal fitness trainer last month I find I actually prefer the bus now.* It's perfectly possible to use past perfect *would rather **have** walked* there, but by no means required. Your first and third alternatives are both idiomatic, but most native speakers would avoid the clumsy repetition of a complex tense form in the second.

Answer (score 1):

Your first choice

> I would rather **have walked** than **take** the bus.

might be said to your travelling companion while still on the bus going to your destination.

> I would rather **have walked** than **taken** the bus.
>   I would rather **have walked** than **have taken** the bus.

Could be said at any time after getting off the bus
Although both are understandable, the second alternative **have taken the bus** sounds clumsy